# Leaving out the Nans within the lambda function for strings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda, nltk, nan

This is somewhat a complicated example. I'm using a function created earlier (document_path_similarity()) in my code in the lambda function.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import nltk

from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
...<some code>

def similarity_score(s1, s2):

# where s1, s2 are the list of synsets.

    lst = []
    # For each synset in s1
    for x in s1:
        # finds the synset in s2 with the largest similarity value
        lst.append(max([y.path_similarity(x) for y in s2 if y.path_similarity(x)])) #so its not None
  
    return sum(lst)/float(len(lst)) 

def document_path_similarity(doc1, doc2):
    # Finds the symmetrical similarity between doc1 and doc2
    synsets1 = doc_to_synsets(doc1)
    synsets2 = doc_to_synsets(doc2)

    return (similarity_score(synsets1, synsets2) + similarity_score(synsets2, synsets1)) / 2
```

Now I am trying to add a new column, s_scores to my dataframe, df, which will show the similarity scores between the strings in columns D1 and D2.

```
    Q   D1                                                  D2
1   1   After more than two years' detention under the...   After more than two years in detention by the ...
2   1   "It still remains to be seen whether the reven...   "It remains to be seen whether the revenue rec...
8   0   "It's a major victory for Maine, and it's a ma...   The Maine program could be a model for other s...
9   1   Microsoft said Friday that it is halting devel...   Microsoft will stop developing versions of its...
10  0   New legit download service launches with PC us...   BuyMusic is the first subscription-free paid d...
```

I have tried to approach this as following.

```
df['s_scores'] = df.apply(lambda x: document_path_similarity(x['D1'], x['D2']), axis=1)
```

This gives

```
ValueError: ('max() arg is an empty sequence', 'occurred at index 8')
```

because, after applying the lambda expressing, the s_score for index 8 is NaN.
This happens for a few more rows in my df.

```
8   0   "It's a major victory for Maine, and it's a ma...   The Maine program could be a model for other s...   NaN
```

If, instead of the document_path_similarity() function, I try to apply similarity_score(), I do not have this error. it runs OK because I have the condition to ensure no NaN values with 'if y.path_similarity(x)' .

I have tried to add 'if x is not None' or 'np.isnan(x)', like this.

```
df['s_scores'] = df.apply(lambda x: document_path_similarity(x.D1, x.D2),axis=1 if x is not None)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have even tried this:

```
df['s_scores'] = df.apply(lambda x: (similarity_score(x.D1, x.D2) + similarity_score(x.D2, x.D1)) / 2,axis=1)
AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'path_similarity'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

So I dont know how to add the exception for the NaNs in my function?

I am also puzzled why document_path_similarity() does not skip NaNs like similarity_score(),  if the former is derived from the latter?

Sorry if its too long as I've tried to explain how my functions work.
I would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: I've already answered this right?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63583219/how-to-rewrite-this-code-into-an-apply-lambda-expression/63585119#63585119. The code is from here: https://socialnetwork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/doc_similarity.html

Comment: I can vote for you on this one and delete the other one. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly the same issue you raised in another question.  [similarity](https://socialnetwork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/doc_similarity.html) has published code with bugs in it.  You have to patch `similarity_score()`

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""    Q   D1                                                  D2
1   1   After more than two years' detention under the...   After more than two years in detention by the ...
2   1   "It still remains to be seen whether the reven...   "It remains to be seen whether the revenue rec...
8   0   "It's a major victory for Maine, and it's a ma...   The Maine program could be a model for other s...
9   1   Microsoft said Friday that it is halting devel...   Microsoft will stop developing versions of its...
10  0   New legit download service launches with PC us...   BuyMusic is the first subscription-free paid d..."""), 
           sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

def similarity_score(s1, s2):
    list1 = []
    for a in s1:
        # patch +[0] at end so never finding max of empty list
        list1.append(max([i.path_similarity(a) for i in s2 if i.path_similarity(a) is not None]+[0]))
    output = sum(list1)/len(list1)
    return output



df = df.assign(
    s_scores=lambda x: x.apply(lambda r: document_path_similarity(r.D1, r.D2), axis=1),
    s_scores2=lambda x: x.apply(lambda r: (similarity_score(doc_to_synsets(r.D1), 
                                                            doc_to_synsets(r.D2)) + 
                                           similarity_score(doc_to_synsets(r.D2), 
                                                            doc_to_synsets(r.D1))) / 2,axis=1)
)

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

**output**

```
 Q                                                 D1                                                 D2  s_scores  s_scores2
 1  After more than two years' detention under the...  After more than two years in detention by the ...  0.782738   0.782738
 1  "It still remains to be seen whether the reven...  "It remains to be seen whether the revenue rec...  0.844444   0.844444
 0  "It's a major victory for Maine, and it's a ma...  The Maine program could be a model for other s...  0.407526   0.407526
 1  Microsoft said Friday that it is halting devel...  Microsoft will stop developing versions of its...  0.371869   0.371869
 0  New legit download service launches with PC us...  BuyMusic is the first subscription-free paid d...  0.048678   0.048678
```

Comment: yes! Nobody answered this question, and I thought maybe that's because it was too long. I can delete the other one later. thank you for helping me!

Comment: It works!!  you've made my day. I could not solve it since yesterday.  [0]  is  it a list with one element, 0? how clever. by the way, it works even without 'is not None', just adding +[0] is enough.

Comment: BTW I found using really simple technique.... 1. call `document_path_similarity()` with string literals outside `apply()` and it fails on same strings. 2. try `max([])` and you get same exception

Answer (score 0):

I have found an alternative way to change similarity_score() so it ignores the empty list.

def similarity_score(s1, s2):

```
lst = []

for x in s1:
    s = [x.path_similarity(y) for y in s2 if x.path_similarity(y) is not None]

    if len(s)>0:
        lst.append(max(s))
output = sum(lst)/len(lst)
return output
```