# How to rewrite this code into an apply-lambda expression?

Tags: pandas, lambda, python-3.6, apply, nan

My dataframe(df) has some NaN entries in the new column, 's_score'  which I can exclude by using func(x).
i.e. the execution of document_path_similarity() leads to some NaNs,  preventing the execution of most_similar_docs() (if I don't use func(x) first).
D1,D2 are df.columns with string data.

```
df
Quality D1                                  D2
0   1   Ms Stewart, the chief executive...  Ms Stewart, 61, its chief executive 
1   1   After more than two years' det...   After more than two years in
```

```
def most_similar_docs():

    def func(x):
        try:
            return document_path_similarity(x['D1'], x['D2'])
        except:
            return np.nan
    df['s_score'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Is there a way to rewrite this code as a one liner?

My attempts such as below lead to 'ValueError: ('max() arg is an empty sequence' or SyntaxError.

```
df['s_scores'] = df.apply(lambda x: document_path_similarity(x.D1, x.D2),axis=1)
paraphrases['s_scores'] = paraphrases.apply(lambda x: document_path_similarity(x.D1, x.D2),axis=1 if np.isnan(x))
```

Comment: what's the import / pip install for document_path_similarity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your `pandas` code.  What I did find is that `similarity_score()` is failing because it's trying to take max of an empty list.   I forced the list to be non-empty by forcing in a zero score.  This is first time I've looked at this library so please don't assume my patch is a good quality patch.

```
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""  Quality  D1                                  D2
0   1   Ms Stewart, the chief executive...  Ms Stewart, 61, its chief executive 
1   1   After more than two years' det...   After more than two years in """), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

def similarity_score(s1, s2):
    list1 = []
    for a in s1:
        # patch +[0] at end so never finding max of empty list
        list1.append(max([i.path_similarity(a) for i in s2 if i.path_similarity(a) is not None]+[0]))
    output = sum(list1)/len(list1)
    return output

df = df.assign(
    s_scores=lambda x: x.apply(lambda r: document_path_similarity(r.D1, r.D2), axis=1)
)

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

**output**

```
 Quality                                  D1                                   D2  s_scores
       1  Ms Stewart, the chief executive...  Ms Stewart, 61, its chief executive  0.838889
       1   After more than two years' det...         After more than two years in  0.912500
```